# Firebase doesn't let me see crash details

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, dsym

The old project of my app used Fabric. (previous to 3.0 version)
I developed a new version (3.0 version and greater) of my app (totally new project) and I tried to implement FirebaseCrashlitycs.

When I look for crashes in Crashlytics dashboard i see an error about dsyms files.
I tried to upload dsyms manually and also including the run script in my project but error still displayed.

[image: Screenshot of the crashlytics dashboard]

How you can see I can see how many crashes attempted but I can't see the details.
The only crash's detail that I can see are about the old project, details migrated from Fabric to Firebase.

Obviously i did something wrong, but i really can't understand what.
The problem is just related to dsyms files?

Comment: You need to upload DYSM symbols to Firebase. Can you tell me the command that you are using to upload DYSM?

Comment: Yes, but i did it, here the command:

Documents/progetti/ios/ProjectName/Pods/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp Documents/progetti/ios/BSD/ProjectName/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios Documents/ProjectName/dysmFolder

p.s DYSM files has been downloaded from appstoreconnect, for example for the 3.0.5 build 2 version.

p.s: The command returns "Successfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols"